# Is there an equivalent of 'Run trace' as in OllyDbg for IDA PRO?

Tags: ida, ollydbg, ida-plugin

I have been looking for the equivalent of the "Run Trace" option of OllyDbg in IDA Pro. Can anyone mention if there is one and how to use it ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IDA Pro offers two tracing options:

1. **Instruction tracing** <kbd>Debugger->Tracing->Instruction Tracing</kbd> It is very slow tracing process, since IDA monitors registers and has to record the address, the instruction, and changes values of registers, that were changed by the instruction.
2. **Function tracing** <kbd>Debugger->Tracing->Function Tracing</kbd>. It is a subcategory of instruction tracing, where only function calls are logged.

There are also three types of tracing events: execution traces, write traces, and read/write traces.

A trace in IDA Pro could by replayed by using *Trace replayer*. It is located within *Debuggers* submenu. You could switch to *Trace-replayer* by going to <kbd>Debugger->Switch Debugger...->Trace replayer</kbd>

[image]

One thing to remember that you have to have trace created before you can replay it. In order to create a trace you will need to do the following:

1. Set a breakpoint at the point where you want you trace started.
2. Run the program with the debugger of your choice.
3. Whenever it breaks, select desired tracing *style* (Instruction or Function)
4. Run as far as necessary. You could set a second breakpoint to stop the trace.
5. You can optionally save the trace.
6. Replay the trace by switching debugger to *Trace replayer*.