# IDA - Read/Write Tracing

Tags: ida

I have *IDA Pro 6.6*, and I'm trying to **trace read/write access** to some address.

According to the documentation it is possible, and there are "nice" menu options under *Debugger*->*Tracing menu*: *"Add write trace"*, *"Add read/write trace"*, *"Add execution trace"*.

I would be happy to try these, but no matter what I've tried all the mentioned menu options are disabled (grayed out). What do I need to do in order to be able to use these options?

Comment: Check out https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2486/is-there-an-equivalent-of-run-trace-as-in-ollydbg-for-ida-pro for more info, or https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/tracing.pdf,  it might help.

Comment: Thanks Dominik! I've gone through this post earlier but it was not helpful for the issue. Anyway, after clicking around I've found the solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Finally I've found: mentioned options are available only from disassembly view, not from hex view. Just place a cursor within disassembly view and right-click menu, as well as main Debugger->Tracing menu will have these options enabled.