# Can't add tracing in IDA, showing it in gray

Tags: ida, windows, debuggers, trace

I added read/write trace to a program. I was able to record the trace with IDA for the first time.
When I run it again, it didn't work.

I tried to do what I did on the first time, adding the read/write trace, but it show it as gray. I ran `Clear trace` but it didn't help:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to put the cursor within the disassembly view (not HEX view), right-click on the disassembly view and then check the option again, it should be available.

[This answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/8364/18080) help me.

Another thing,
You can't trace if the instruction has breakpoint. You need to remove the breakpoint and then assign the trace.

If you set a function to be traced, and it doesn't print anything, put the cursor on the desired function, on the menu press `Debugger -> Tracing -> Function tracing`.  Try again.

You can view all the traces in the breakpoint window by pressing  `Ctrl+Alt+B`.